# Python to fit a linear-plateau curve

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy

I have curve that initially Y increases linearly with X, then reach a plateau at point C.
In other words, the curve can be defined as:

```
if X < C: 
    Y = k * X + b
else: 
    Y = k * C + b
```

The training data is a list of X ~ Y values. I need to determine k, b and C through a machine learning approach (or similar), since the data is noisy and refection point C changes over time. I want something more robust than get C through observing the current sample data.
How can I do it using sklearn or maybe scipy?

Answer (score 0):

WLOG you can say the second equation is

```
Y = C
```

looks like you have a linear regression to fit the line and then a detection point to find the constant.

You know that in the high values of `X`, as in `X > C` you are already at the constant.  So just check how far back down the values of `X` you get the same constant.

Then do a linear regression to find the line with value of X,  `X <= C`

Comment: I need a robust approach to find C if possible. The input data sets would change over time, k, b and C are not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is nonlinear
I think the smartest way to solve this is to do these steps:

1. find the maximum value of Y which is equal to k*C+b

> ```
> M=max(Y)
> ```

2. drop this maximum value from your dataset

> df1 = df[df.Y != M]

and then you have simple dataset to fit your X to Y and you can use sklearn for that

Comment: I need a robust approach to find C if possible. The input data is noisy and it would change over time, k, b and C are not fixed.

Comment: So maybe it would be better to iterate through X and each time you have a 'c' 
run your curve fitting for that 'c' and save the condition where you have the best R^2